# Which ML method for multiclass (non-binary) text classification should I choose (from SparkML)?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, text-classification

I am working on a quite big dataset that will be processed on the cluster, so this is why I am using PySpark for that puropose.

The presentable records of this dataset have a such structure:

```
|RowNoIndex|ReceivedDate|             Product|          Subproduct|               Issue| 
+----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         0|  07/29/2013|       Consumer Loan|        Vehicle loan|Managing the loan...|
|         1|  07/29/2013|Bank account or s...|    Checking account|Using a debit or ...|
|         2|  07/29/2013|Bank account or s...|    Checking account|Account opening, ...
```

After some preprocessing/data cleansing operations I would like to create and then obviously train a model that will classify issues (`Issue`) into some categories,  that are still unknown. I am a newbie in the ML area. I have readen some articles about TF-IDF, but not sure if this could be suitable for this case. Could anyone help? Thank you in advance. If you need more information do not hestiate to comment.

Comment: The first question you have to answer for yourself is, if you want an algorithm to suggest you potential categories (unsupervised learning) or if you want to provide the categories and label some of your data by yourself (supervised learning). But your question is too broad for stackoverflow. You should ask such a question at [data science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It could be supervised learning as categories are already applied.

Comment: Still to broad for stackoverflow. Just look for text classification and spark. There are a plenty of different approaches and you really have to try which one works for your data.

Comment: suggest to search the web for "text classification using `tf-idf`" and using `LDA`